# Facebook Ad Libary -- Type of Token (for Authentication)

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone tried using the CLI for the ad library API? I am trying to pull data (using cURL) and it needs an access token. Is this the user access token I create from the Graph API that it references?

Comment: The documentation for the endpoints you are using should contain the info what kind of access token you need to use, and what permissions are required.

Comment: @CBroe It is strange, for the permissions I require are not listed as I am trying to access data regarding the ads of political ads published by other pages, rather than my users for an app I have admin control over. I made a user token with random permissions and it seemed to work out in the end.